# How to write dependencies in gradle build

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, jar

I am start to learn gradle today, and I am go to https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/gradle-spring-mvc-web-project-example/ to learn.

In the `build.gradle` document, the dependencies is written as follow:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'

}
```

Know that `logback-classic:1.1.3` is a jar name. But I am confusing with the `ch.qos.logback`, is it referring to package name?

If yes, then I would like try to compile another jar, which is `slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar`.

So I write compile `org.slf4j:slf4j-api-1.7.7`, but hit not found error.

Can someone point me my mistake? Sorry I am very new, hopefully this is not a silly question and being down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the convention is `groupId:artifactId:version`

try `org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7`

Comment: is my mistake. It should be `:` instead of `-`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you similar with maven? 
Maven and Gradle use the same repository. 
For example: 
Maven setting:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And gradle setting:

```
testCompile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.1.3'
```

or

```
testCompile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
```

So with your slf4j, lets check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7

It would be

```
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.7'
```

Comment: Scope test in maven is `testCompile` in gradle.

Comment: That just example man. Anw, thanks for your note!